# Android Jersey Client com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException

Tags: android, rest, jersey

I am using jersey client from my android app to connect to a web service.
The version of `android is 1.6 (api level 4)`

I have referenced `jersey-core-1.12.jar and jersey-client-1.12.jar` libs.

When I call a request with `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) I am getting the following exception:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.sun.jersey.core.util.MultivaluedMapImpl, and MIME media type, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, was not found
```

**Using the same code with JDK 1.6 update 04 - all works fine.**

Here is the sample of my server code for the request:

```
@Path("/" + RequestNames.LOGIN)
public class Login {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Response login(
            @FormParam(RequestParams.USER_NAME_PARAM) String userName,
            @FormParam(RequestParams.PASSWORD_PARAM) String password) {
...
```

Here is the sample of my client code for the request:

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
        formData.add(RequestParams.USER_NAME_PARAM, userName);
        formData.add(RequestParams.PASSWORD_PARAM, password);
        ClientResponse response =
                service.path(REST_PATH).path(RequestNames.LOGIN).type(
                        MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
```

Comment: Try using MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData as an attribute for the login method.

Comment: Mohan, same effect. Works with jdk 1.6 update 04, but doesn't work with android 1.6.

Comment: in the end I switched to apache HttpClient. And it worked perfectly both with apache libs with jdk 1.6 update 4, and in android without any additional libs

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the

> A message body writer for Java type, class com.sun.jersey.core.util.MultivaluedMapImpl

error and it ended up to be a maven dependency issue. Instead of using the single `jersey-*` artifacts I included `jersey-bundle` and it worked. E.g.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This actuelly worked for me, should investigate why, and whats missing in the other packages. Replaced: jersey-multipart, jersey-client and jersey-core with the bundle.