# Using Twitter search API

Tags: java, twitter, jersey-client

I am trying to build a Jersey Rest Client to use the Twitter search api.

The code is as folows:

```
   package twitter.client.example;

   import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
   import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
   import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
   import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
   import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;


   public class TwitterClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();

        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client
           .resource("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?      lang=en&q=pizza");


        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                   .get(ClientResponse.class);



        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + response.getStatus());
        }

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        System.out.println(output);

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

}
```

}

When I run this, I get a `com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException:` `java.net.ConnectException:Connection timed out: connect exception`

Is there something that I am missing out in the code or can it be due to proxy settings? Do I need to incorporate OAuth or is the search api still unauthenticated?

Thanks,
Sakshi

Comment: Do you have the required jars, or what jars have you used  ?

Comment: Have a look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996866/android-jersey-client-com-sun-jersey-api-client-clienthandlerexception

Comment: Do you get any response while using the web browser ?